# Give a proof by cases that shows that $n(n ^2 − 1)(n + 2) $ is a multiple of $4$, for all integers $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Give a proof by cases that shows that $n(n ^2 − 1)(n + 2) $ is a multiple of  $4$, for all integers $n$

I have already done case 1 where n is even. I am doing case 2 where n is odd and I'm a bit confuse how to finish off the problem..Uploaded a picture of my work..
Is this work sufficient enough to prove that it is a multiple of 4? The 6k would not have any affect of the result in general?

I feel it is wrong because of the 6k. Right now my thoughts are if (statement) is a multiple of 4, then (statement) is a multiple of 2 as well. And work from there.

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Syc.png)

Comment: Do you mean $$n(n^2-1)(n+2)$$?

Comment: yes, correct. will update the title

Comment: Hint:  your expression is $(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)$ .  Show that one of those factors is a multiple of $4$,

Comment: Awww come on man, it's fine to post already answered questions (especially if you are a new guy).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write your term in the form $$(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$
So if $n$ is odd, then both of the factors above are even.
From this you can show that 4 must divide $n(n^2-1)(n+2)$

Answer (score 0):

You went wrong at this stage:
$$n(n^2-1)(n+2)=(2k+1)((2k+1)-1)(2k+3)$$
Can you see where?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it.

> n(n+1)(n-1)(n+2)
>   =(2k+1)(2k)(2k+2)(2k+3)
>   =($4k^2$+2k)(2k+2)(2k+3)
>   =($8k^3$+$12k^2$+4k)(2k+3)
>
> > =4($2k^3$+$3k^2$+k)(2k+3)

edit 1:lemme know if there's any objections

Comment: Only objection: use Mathjax!

Comment: My objection is that your method is much too complicated. Just notice that when $n$ is odd, both $(n-1)$ and $(n+1)$ are even. Hence at least two factors $2$. When $n$ is even, so is $(n+2)$. Again at least two factors $2$. That completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases :

If $n$ is odd, then $n-1$ and $n+1$ both even . the product $(n-1)(n+1)$ is a multiple of $4$, so is $(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$.

If $n$ is even the $n+2$ is also even. The product $n(n+2)$ is a multiple of $4$ , so is $(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$[(n^2-1)][n(n+2)].$

1) Let $n$ be odd.

$[(n^2-1)] =(n+1)(n-1);$

$n+1, n-1$ are even,

$2| (n+1)$ and $2|(n-1)$, hence

$4|(n-1)(n+1).$

2) Let $n$ be even.

$[n(n+2)];$

$2|n$ and $2|(n+2)$, hence

$4|n(n+2).$